# How can i do a obligatory link?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I'm programming on ASP/VB and I want to make a link that is required to click before doing any other action

It is a form which in order to continue to the next screen, you need to click on a link, otherwise you can not continue on the form. That the next step is to click on a button that sends you to a confirmation page

```
<a style="margin-left:7%;color:red;" id="test" target="_blank" runat="server" visible="False" href="https://google.es">xxxx</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Disabling a Button until the link is clicked.

```
<a href="https://google.es" id="RequiredLink" target="_blank">Required Link</a>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" />

<script>
    $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#RequiredLink').click(function () {
        $('#<%= Button11.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', false);
    });
</script>
```